# 70s book written by a male witch about polar energy and witch hunts

Tags: story-identification, witches

I read a book in my teens (70's) written by a real male witch. The plot as I remember it was...scientists had discovered a way to use the earth as an energy source by installing large poles at the north and south poles basically creating a battery but something goes wrong and instead of taking the blame they blame the witches and a witch hunt ensues.

I even remember the back cover. It was an old man with a beard sitting at a table with a typewriter and it said his name and that he was a practicing witch.

Answer (score 8):

**Omega** by Stewart Farrar.  Stewart Farrar was a practicing witch. Omega is about scientists discovering the Mendoza effect; deriving energy by giant poles stuck into the earth. However, the project releases madness inducing dust, which the British government decides to blame on the witches. Who are then hunted by the government-sponsored motorcycle gangs.
[image]

[image]

Comment: "hunted by the govenment-sponsored motorcycle gangs" is possibly the best phrase i've read this morning